# Django : null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint(Issue is at admin)

Tags: django, postgresql

On adding the data from admin panel in django, on adding the records, the postgresql is throwing the error as primary key is getting the `null` value. As it must be auto incremented.

Please let me know how to fix this issue and why it may be persisting .

As previously, this issue got fixed automatically.

Comment: Post your models

Answer (score 0):

Man, I'm running into the same problem it seems, out of nowhere.

In a state of bewildered frustration, I've come up with this hacky hacky hacky "solution":

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    def clean(self):
        if not self.id:
            self.id = MyModel.objects.last().id + 1
```

This is really not how things should be, but for me it works for now. Sometimes that's all that counts.